# Using Electron Code in Browser

Tags: node.js, web-applications, cross-platform, desktop-application, electron

I want to create a cross-platform app in **Desktop** and **Web Browser** with electron and each of these have a separate database, *SqLite* for Desktop and *MySQL* for Web. is logically possible to code once for both of them?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to the functionality that is specific to Electron or the Browser by checking if Node-specific globals are available. They will be available in Electron, but they won't be in a traditional browser application.

You could do this with something along the lines of:

```
var isElectron = false;
if (typeof 'process' !== 'undefined') {
  isElectron = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve ,I mean, can i reuse Electron code blocks in browser side (http) or I have to writing browser side again?

Comment: @myvahid You can definitely reuse code on the browser-side. In Electron, you can use `require` to require a file or `electron.remote.require` if you want to pull it code but have it execute from the main process.